# Add date values with other format in sqldatabase from back

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I have a gridvieww and sqldatasource.

I have some columns: `Name, Date TK (type DATE)`.

I have a lot of rows to add in the data table.

For example: John 30.12.2012 . and when I copy the rows from excel and I paste them into data table , the column Date doesn't allow this format of date. and I need to make it allow.
[image]

Comment: Where do you _paste_ it?

Comment: Is it a programming question?

Comment: Well since this is an asp.net project , and I'm using sql database from it , and paste some values in the datatable ..but it won't accept them so I think I need to change something from asp..settings..or I dun know

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "paste" here - but you should be using `DateTime` for the date values - parse as soon as you can, and keep it in `DateTime` format for as long as you can, including when talking to the database. Avoid string conversions unless you have to.

Comment: take a look now please, post updated

Comment: Can't you change Date format of your excel sheet to mm.dd.yyyy ?

Comment: Do you mean a DataGridView that you're pasting that data into?

Comment: Yes I mean the data grid view, so I'm pasting the information there and then I'll view then in gridview

Answer (score 0):

You can use reformat your dates with :

```
DateTime time = DateTime.Now; // Or the date you have/need
String format = "mm.dd.yyyy";
String goodTime = time.ToString(format));
```

Take a look at [this article.](http://www.dotnetperls.com/datetime-format)

Answer (score 0):

Set the date field equal to

```
type.Date.ToString("MM.dd.yyyy");
```

However, at our company, we've run into several issues with international dates and saving to a Database.  The format we've found that works best is:

```
type.Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
```

Comment: you misunderstood my question

Comment: Your question isn't particularly clear. What do you mean by 'paste them into a datatable'?  DataTables are programming objects; copy-and-paste is a Windows UI operation. How are you mixing the two?

Comment: You mentioned a sqldatasource.  Based on your original question, that would be how you take it from your DataGrid and get it to save into the Database.  Please explain your problem further then, and provide some more code.

Comment: The simplest solution for that then would probably be Damith's suggestion to temporarily change the format in the Excel spreadsheet to MM/DD/YYYY and switch it back when you're done.  There is no format option if you were to right-click on the Column in the Solution Explorer window on the right?

Comment: nope there are no format options and..changing format won't be a good solution for me